# Stop plot edges being cut off in bipartite package (plotweb)

Tags: r, bipartite

With the plotweb() function in the bipartite package in R, I've created a network, but some of the labels are too long for the plot area. As a result, they are being cut off at the top and bottom (I've included a picture).

I'm trying to make it fit in the plot, or if not possible, to be able to export it as an image without the edges being cut off.

I've tried par(mar=c(), but that doesn't seem to do anything. ybig() can allow the top half to fit in, but it doesn't change the bottom section.

[See photo: labels being cut off from the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTvLR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the argument `y.lim` could be adjusted in such cases. From `help(plotweb)`, about `y.lim`:

> [...] Useful if labels are plotted outside the plotting region and for multitrophic plots [...]

Here is an example:

```
library(bipartite)

data(Safariland)
# Forge some long names/labels
cn <- colnames(Safariland)
rn <- rownames(Safariland)
colnames(Safariland) <- paste(cn, cn)
rownames(Safariland) <- paste(rn, rn)

# plotweb with trying to fit the labels - tweak y.lim until you get it right
plotweb(Safariland, text.rot = 90, y.lim = c(-1.5, 4))
```

[image]